# Dynamic URL WITH EACH PAGE having Shopping.php?item=0001

Tags: php

I use a SQL database and a WHILE LOOP to display the contents of the database on the main page and am currently trying to incorporate a Facebook "like" button for each and every item on the page.

Currently every item listed in the database is displayed on Shopping.php
I need the server to be able to create a page with a unique address for each item in the database so that the "like" buttons don't all link back to the Shopping.php page.

What I am imagining is something like "/Shopping.php?item=0001" that will link to a page dedicated to that one single item.

Thanks for your time.

Please if you could give a code how to do it , it would be great help

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET["item"]))
{
    // Fetch information about item with ID = $_GET["item"] from database and render a page for it.
}
```

Was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this would work, only change is, you need to get the item number from the URL and refine your SQL query.

```
if(isset($_GET["item"]){
sql = "select * from items where item_id = $_GET['item']";
\\display results after executing this sql
}
```

But if you want to optimize it to search engine, i recommend you keep your urls as

```
shopping/item1
shopping/item2 etc
```